# OSX Installing Ruby with rbenv

Tags: ruby, macos, rbenv

I have installed Ruby on OSX using `rbenv` following these instructions: https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.9-mavericks

I installed 2.2.2 however, even after adding it as the global value in `rbenv` using `rbenv global 2.2.2`, the `ruby -v` command still returns `ruby 1.8.7`.

Now, I know that in my `/usr/bin`, `ruby` is still symlinked to the default OSX version (1.8.7).  And I could change the symlink.  But I'm wondering what the best practice is here, and how `rbenv` is supposed to work in terms of multiple ruby versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `rbenv rehash`, which you should do after installing anything Ruby (or Gem) related.

Have you added this to .bashrc (or similar for your set up)?

```
export RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/var/rbenv
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
```

and

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
```

Comment: I did try that already however the symlinked version is still executed.

Comment: Start a new Terminal session, too. (I added a couple more items to configure your system.)

Comment: Your edit helped me figure it out.  In the Ruby instructions it said to add 
`if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi` to my `.bash_profile`.  However, i'm using ZSH!  So after adding it to my `.zshrc` everything is now working